# How can I maintain consistent IDs across DB rebuilds?

Tags: database, postgresql, data-warehouse

I'm writing a green-field Data Warehouse, and one of the constraints that we have on the business side is to present to our users a consistent ID mapping, for example:

```
ID  Company
--  -------
1   Acme
2   LexCorp
3   Stark International
```

However, we also would like to have the option to completely rebuild the DB from scratch, using the code and raw data files, so that we can ensure that our process is consistent, and as an additional redundancy in making sure that we always have a way to keep our system running.

We will be regularly importing new data, from multiple vendors, so I don't have a guarantee that data will be imported in the same order each time.

I'd strongly prefer that the IDs be natural numbers, which precludes simply having a hash be the ID (along with the potential for collisions). And I would also prefer to have the raw data be the driving force for populating the database (rather than occasionally writing a file with all the company IDs, and then squeezing them back into where they should be later).

Is there a way to achieve both these goals? That is, Can I start from scratch and reimport all my data, and still have a way to maintain the same IDs each time?

We're planning on using PostgreSQL, with most of our ETL pipelines for cleaning and processing data in R and Python.

Comment: You may reset you data warehouse *except for the mapping table* from the natural company keys to your surrogate keys. There is no other option that this *trivial solution*. And BTW the *more challenging task* ist to keep the surrogate key identical if the natural key of the company is changing.

Comment: I'm completely okay with natural keys  changing in the DB, but in the presentation layer, they need to remain the same. Is there a good way to generate those surrogate keys procedurally?

Comment: Whats wrong with the approach of saving the mapping table over the reset? This is IMHO the only option available to preserve the surrogate key stability.